# Sub Query SQL to display grouping, count, put it on up

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have one table on database

```
No  |  Nomor ID  | Name   | chairman (if as chairman id=1, if not = 0)
1   | 1234       | Brian  | 1
2   | 1234       | Dol    | 0
3   | 5555       | Mon    | 0
4   | 5555       | Tue    | 1
5   | 5555       | Nom    | 0
```

I want to, display it with

```
Nomor ID |  Name | Chairman | count 
1234     | Brian |     1    |  2
5555     | Tue   |     1    |  3
```

I was try any possibilities.. but can't , to display "name" put on it like that

May you know solution

Comment: I think that you can solve some of this yourself

Comment: but i cant still solve .. i still try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT 
  t1.`Nomor ID`,
  t1.Name,
  t1.chairman,
  t2.count 
FROM
  `mytable` t1 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      `Nomor ID`,
      COUNT(`No`) AS `count` 
    FROM
      `mytable` 
    GROUP BY `Nomor ID`) t2 
    ON t1.`Nomor ID` = t2.`Nomor ID` 
WHERE t1.chairman = '1'
```

Check the **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c37fd7/1)**

Comment: How is this any different from my answer?

Comment: actually same .. but your code can't run because this  t2.totalcount AS 'count' and `Nomor ID` should be t1.`Nomor ID` .. sorry @hjpotter92 .. i confused

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    `Nomor ID`, 
    `Name`,
    `Chairman`,
    t2.totalcount AS 'count'
FROM tblName t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS totalcount,
        `Nomor ID`
    FROM tblName
    GROUP BY `Nomor ID`
) t2
    ON t2.`Nomor ID` = t1.`Nomor ID`
WHERE t1.chairman = 1
```

The above query should work as expected.

Comment: @tara so does this

Comment: it using inner join,, i just have one table.. so it can't .. @Strawberry

Comment: @tara your logic is flawed. Try it.

Comment: @tara Replace the `tblName` with the actual name of your table. The query will work.

Comment: I wanna ask @hjpotter92  GROUP BY `No`) t2 ON t2.`No` = t1.`No` .. this No or Nomor ID ??

Comment: @tara They are `Nomor ID`. Sorry about that.

Comment: if nomor ID, cant run.. but if no run.. but the result, name still can't display in up

Comment: wait .. @hjpotter92

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. **GROUP BY** is your friend:

```
SELECT
  `Nomor ID`
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`Name`), ',', 1) AS `Name`
  , IF(`chairman` = 1,1,0) AS `chairman`,
  count(*) AS `count`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `Nomor ID`;
```

Comment: i was try.. but.. name display still "Nom" .

Comment: @tara - i have change my answer, sorry

Comment: i was try.. if i add data .. name still can't display .. maybe i try again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.`Nomor ID`,t.Name,sum(case when chairman=1 then 1 else 0 end) as chairman,count(`No`) as Cnt from table1 join (select `Nomor ID`,Name from table1 where chairman=1  ) t on t.`Nomor ID`=table1.`Nomor ID` group by `Nomor ID`
```

The above query will give as you expected.